# Error Installing Windows SQL Server on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have been completely unable to install Windows SQL Server Express on Windows Server 2012 R2.  Every time, I get:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Setup

The following error has occurred:

Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%25400x4BDAF9BA%25401306%254026

So far the link above has been useless to me.  I've tried installing it on the Administrator Account and right clicking run as administrator.  I just can't seem to get the damn thing to work.

The error log points at a certificate issue: "Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate. "

Comment: "Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes."

Comment: The link you shared is broken

Comment: Unfortunately thats the link given to me by the program.  As to the SQL Server error log it indicates that "Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate. "

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this guide here seemed to fix things for me.  I believe that MS SQL Server was for some reason unable to access the certificates already installed on the computer.

https://thedataspecialist.wordpress.com/category/sql-server-2012/